# GCE cloud nat "Dropped received packets"

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

We are using GKE autopilot + Cloud NAT to allow our GKE to connect to the remote database. Now the thing is we have an error with dropped received packages:

[image: chart showing dropped received packets rate]

We tried to add a second IP to the Cloud NAT to make GKE work via 2 IPs. But as expected, GKE works only with one. We suspect that the problem is insufficient bandwidth per 1 IP. It seems our Cloud NAT can't get a lot of data from the database and it needs a wider bandwidth.

Do we understand this problem correctly? How to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ivan, Have you found the issue/resolution?

Comment: Hi. Can't say whether I found or not.. But I wrote google support and we was able to reduce lost packages rate. They told me to check "Timeout for protocol connections" on Cloud NAT settings. I increased timeouts such as: TCP established to 1200, TCP transitory to 60, TCP time wait to 80, UDP to 80. That helped. Not 100% but enough for us.